# Jquery get parent OL x position

Tags: jquery

```
$(".subTab").css("left", $(this).parent("ol").position().left);
```

Dear JQuery users, why wont the above work?

Comment: Have checked what *this* is here?

Comment: We don't know the context so we can't say why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` in your code doesn't refer to the selected element(*subTab*).

```
$(".subTab").css("left", function(){
   return $(this).closest("ol").position().left;
})
```